# Browser.min.js file for React JS

Tags: reactjs

Where can I find and download a `browser.min.js` file for `react.js`? I'm struggling for so long trying to find it.

Comment: [Try this](https://github.com/kud/browser-js), or I failed to understand that there's a specific `browser js` that is developed just for `react.js`

Comment: What is `browser.min.js` ?

Comment: @azium I also got this confuse before, but we should understand that it comes from `Babel-core` here https://cdnjs.com/libraries/babel-core . as least I think it's not a good naming, since compare babel-core with browser.min.js, it has nothing relationship, right. finally just get this, it's babel core, it could let browser to support es6.

Answer (score 5):

You mean babel browser file for compile react file in browser?
This file was removed from babel project (therefore you have problems to find it), please look to documentation: [link](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/browser/)

They advice to precompile file in server side.

But If you need it, it is still available in some cdns, you can get/use it from here: [link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js)

Answer (score 2):

its just so easy go to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js and save the file as browser.min.js

now you can try offline unlike they don't recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I think most guys can not understand what's the `browser.min.js`, and where it comes from.

Actually, it's just the `Babel-core` library, check this here https://cdnjs.com/libraries/babel-core. anyway, I think it got a bad naming, since you just can not associate it with `Babel-core`.